# How to get Docker Image locally in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, percona, percona-xtradb-cluster

I have K8S cluster on machine(CentOS) which is not connected to internet, I mostly get docker images from the online machines and load like `docker load -i myimages.tar.gz` and add `imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent` in manifest.yaml. It works fine.

Now i am testing Percona XtradbCluster Operator which has `imagePullPolicy: Always` as i cant change this and i am getting below error

```
Error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:54103->[::1]:53: read: connection refused
```

How i can make changes on docker or kubernetes so it only get images locally without changing `imagePullPolicy`?

**Update1:**
I tried to patch statefulset but it didn't work as these resources are directly managed by operator so after my changes operator override it immediately

```
 kubectl patch statefulset cluster1-pxc -p '{"spec": {"template": {"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"pxc","imagePullPolicy":"Never"}]}}}}'
```

Comment: You can run a pod manually based on a specific image (without manifest) which allows you to set the policy, if that helps

`kubectl run pod podname --image=image-name --image-pull-policy=IfNotPresent --generator=run-pod/v1`

Comment: But these pods get launched by StatefulSet and that StatefulSet manifest get create dynamically by Operator code.

Comment: Can you `kubectl edit statefulset ss-name` and change the policy?

Comment: @SonNguyen Sorry i forgot to mention but i tried and it didnt work as these resources are directly managed by operator so after my changes operator override it immediatly

kubectl patch statefulset cluster1-pxc -p '{"spec": {"template": {"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"pxc","imagePullPolicy":"Never"}]}}}}'

Comment: My last two cents is could you somehow extract the config (like `get -o yaml`) and then start the statefulset manually. That maybe a workaround if you can't get the config into the software.